# .NET Nuget package conflicts

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget

I'm using a custom package source for some nuget packages in Visual Studio.

I am developing stuff on my own in VSCode that will NOT build unless I'm connected to my work VPN. (It can't restore json.net).  The error I'm getting is:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error [My work's custom package source]
```

How do I tell VSCode to remove that custom package source? There are no files in my solution that contain the custom package URL and I don't see it in the NuGet.targets file either.

Comment: VSCode is a great Text editor and does many things. You should use Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, which is free as well, I switch workflows between both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. In Visual Studio 2017 CE you can clear nuget packages, control nuget package sources with ease

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the NuGet configuration files, these exist in machine, user and project level, see the [NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) on these locations.

An easy way to change the behavior temporarily is to create a `nuget.config` file in the directory where your source code is (maybe a level above so git / your vcs doesn't add it) that clears all other feeds and adds back the nuget.org feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When opening a project in VS code or VS or building from command line, this will no longer consider the globally configured feeds.

You can also do the inverse and add a nuget.config without the `<clear/>` element but a feed entry for your work source to all your work projects.